# Tiles not centered within web part in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, script, tiles

I am completely new to SharePoint and trying to design/create a page as requested by the company I work for. The issue I'm having is all the tiles I've created within a web part are aligned left. I did create a script editor and added a code that would automatically wrap the tiles so those scroll bars won't appear; however the tiles are not lined up. Any way this can be achieved please? Thanks.[image]

Comment: can u post your html and css?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML with Proper CSS styles.

Take one main div, give required width and set margin as auto for center align.
Place your tiles in this main div. Then your tiles should appear in the center of the web part.

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about programming and I don't even know where to begin to apply your suggestion... but thank you regardless.

Answer (score 0):

As Nagababu suggested, you need to wrap your code with a `div`. The wrapper div will contain following CSS.

```
<div style='display: block; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;'>
    your html goes here.......
</div>
```

By default HTML div display property is `block`, so you can omit it if you are not using any custom display property in main css for divs.